# Using php and jquery to load MySQL data into website

Tags: php

My goal is to take data from a MySQL database and then use jquery to load it into divs on the page using the jquery .load() function. I'm new to php, so I'd like to keep it to a minimum and really use jquery to do most of the processing. I can connect to the database, perform a query, and close it, so accessing the database isn't a problem. I'm just not sure what the best way to process that data is. I'm having trouble pulling all these concepts together. Once I get a simple example working, I can go from there.

php to connect to mysql database:

```
 <?php
    //connect to database
    $dbhost = "yourhost";
    $dbuser = "youruser";
    $dbpass = "yourpass";
    $dbname = "yourdb";
    $connection = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

    //Perform database query
    $query  = "SELECT * ";
    $query .= "FROM userInfo ";
    $query .= "WHERE ID = 1 ";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

    ?>
```

Code to retrieve the row of data on the user (this is where I need help):

```
    <?php
    $user_data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    //now I want to add more code here to collect all the entries in the row to load into the html.  
    //Or can I do it in jquery?
    }
    ?>
```

html:

```
<div id='ID_number'></div>
<div id='first_name'></div>
<div id='last_name'></div>
```

close connection:

```
<?php  mysqli_free_result($result); ?>
<?php  mysqli_close($connection); ?>
```

Comment: Ah you using ajax? If your not you don't need jquery. Just print the data using php.

Answer (score 2):

You can use as below :

```
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $rows[] = $r;
}
print json_encode($rows);
```

In your Html use jquery as below :

```
$.get( "test.php", function( data ) {
  alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
});
```

//It return JSON data. parse it in HTML

[Here](http://www.w3schools.com/Php/php_ajax_database.asp) is the good explanation of ajax

Or

If you are not using AJAX :

```
<?php
    while($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        echo "<div id='id'>". $data['idfieldname']. "</div>
              <div id='fname'>". $data['fname field name']. "</div>
              <div id='lname'>". $data['last_name_field_name']. "</div>";
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
    while($user_data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        echo "<div id='ID_number'>". $user_data['id_field_name']. "</div>
              <div id='first_name'>". $user_data['first_name_field_name']. "</div>
              <div id='last_name'>". $user_data['last_name_field_name']. "</div>";
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Are you missing a while loop somewhere?